# Nearly free electron model: How to diagonalize the perturbation Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, perturbation-theory

In the Nearly free electron model, we treat a weak periodic potential as a perturbation to the free electron model so
$$H_{tot}=H_0+V(\vec{r})$$
where $H_0=\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}$ and $V(\vec{r})=V(\vec{r}+\vec{R})$ for any direct lattice vector
$\vec{R}$. The eigenstates of the unperturbed free electron Hamiltonian are simply plane waves of the form $|\vec{k}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L^3}}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}}$. Now because this system exhibits degeneracy, we must utilize degenerate perturbation theory and diagonalize the *perturbation* hamiltonian $V$ with respect to the *unperturbed* basis (the plane wave basis). That is, we must determine the eigenvalues in the following equation
$$\begin{bmatrix}\langle k|V|k\rangle&\langle k|V|k'\rangle\\\langle k'|V|k\rangle&\langle k'|V|k'\rangle\end{bmatrix} \, \begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta  \end{bmatrix} =E\begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta  \end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}V_0&\langle k|V|k'\rangle\\\langle k'|V|k\rangle&V_0\end{bmatrix} \, \begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta  \end{bmatrix} =E\begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta  \end{bmatrix}\tag{1}$$
Note that the diagonal terms are simply the average value of the weak potential (denoted $V_0$) since they are equal to the zeroth Fourier coefficient of the expansion of the periodic potential.
But now my textbook (Steve Simon : The Oxford Solid State Basics) does not diagonalize the *perturbed* hamiltonian, $V$, in the unperturbed basis but instead diagonalizes the *whole* hamiltonian ($H_{tot}$) to get that

$$\begin{bmatrix}\langle k|H_{tot}|k\rangle&\langle k|H_{tot}|k'\rangle\\\langle k'|H_{tot}|k\rangle&\langle k'|H_{tot}|k'\rangle\end{bmatrix} \, \begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta  \end{bmatrix} =E\begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta  \end{bmatrix}\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}\epsilon_0 (k)&\langle k|H_{tot}|k'\rangle\\\langle k'|H_{tot}|k\rangle&\epsilon_0(k')\end{bmatrix} \, \begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta  \end{bmatrix} =E\begin{bmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta  \end{bmatrix}$$
This is very different to the result I get in eq 1 when I diagonalize the perturbation as opposed to diagonalizing the full hamiltonian like he does. Why does he diagonalize the whole hamiltonian instead of the perturbation? It seems like he is incorrectly applying perturbation theory because in Griffiths QM, it is made very clear that you diagonalize the perturbation hamiltonian. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do these not just differ by $\epsilon(k)$?

Comment: @jacob1729 Using my methodology (which is the same as Griffiths), the diagonal elements can be set to zero (since we can always set $V_0=0$) whilst his methodology does lead to diagonal elements of $\epsilon_0(k)$. But my methodology would yield a characteristic equation of $(V_0-E)(V_0-E)-|\langle k|V|k'\rangle|^2=0$ whilst his would yield $(\epsilon_0(k)-E)(\epsilon_0(k')-E)-|\langle k|V|k'\rangle|^2=0$ which in general is different to my result? My other issue is why his methodology (diagonalizing H instead of V ) should work at all since its not the way any textbooks teach it?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding degenerate perturbation theory then. The procedure Griffith's describes gives the energy perturbations $\Delta E$. Simon is doing the same thing but since he wants the total energy $E=E_0+\Delta E$ he has added in $E_0 \mathbb{1}$.

Comment: Okay I think I understand now. So you are saying that in Griffiths procedure, he determines the first order correction ($\Delta E$) by diagonalizing the perturbation $V$ in the unperturbed basis and then he adds this to the unperturbed energy $E_0$ to get the estimate  $E=E_0 +\Delta E$. This, however, is identical to what Simon does: he simply diagonalizes the full Hamiltonian ($H_{tot}$) in the unperturbed basis to immediately get the resulting estimate of $E=E_0+\Delta E$. These two methods (actually the same method but Griffiths breaks it into two steps?) always yield identical results?

Comment: @jacob1729 Am I correct in my thinking above?

Comment: Yes that seems accurate.

Comment: @jacob1729 Okay, its crystal clear now. Thanks so much for the help! If its beneficial to you, you can post a very simple answer which I'd be more than willing to accept. Thanks again!